# Regexp - javascript = как можно это ускорить?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
// npn install performance-now
var now = require("performance-now");
var start = now();
var end = now();
// здесь специально сделана ошибка "::" - для проверки...
var cmd='{"AFDS":"0","Fn"::"[cr@1,cr@2]"}';

//получатель результата
function agent(taskbox){
 console.log(taskbox.msg,taskbox.jsonbox,(start-end).toFixed(3));
}

function checkJson(data,cb) {

 var check_proc={
     "jsonbox":"json str",
     "err":['",',',"','{,',',}','[,',',]','::'],
     "msg":[],
     "agent":{} };
     check_proc.filtr_0=new RegExp(/[^/\[|/\]|/\{|/\}|/\"|/\:/]/gim);
     check_proc.filtr_1=new RegExp(/\"":""/g),
     check_proc.filtr_2=new RegExp(/\[]/g||/\()/g),
     check_proc.filtr_3=new RegExp(/\{}/g);

 // это предварительная подготовка к проверке строки на валидность JSON..
     check_proc.jsonbox=((((data.replace(check_proc.filtr_0,''))
     .replace(check_proc.filtr_1,''))
     .replace(check_proc.filtr_2,''))
     .replace(check_proc.filtr_1,''))
     .replace(check_proc.filtr_3,'');
return cb(check_proc);
// ..дальше код проверки, с ним все ок.. 
 }

checkJson(cmd,agent);
```

-0.033 -> как то многовато... :-(

Comment: А зачем вы заворачиваете регекспы в регекспы?

Comment: Создаю объекты типа regexp с необходимыми параметрами, что бы потом в коде удобно использовать.. можно конечно нарисовать много раз всю строку регексах но не комильфо как то..  поэтому разбито по частям.. думаю на скорость это не влияет, точно..

Comment: Я про new Regexp(/.../). Ведь /.../ это уже регулярка, зачем её в new Regexp запихивать?